# Daily Local Notifications but with different text each day

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am needing some help because I am new to coding. I have been creating an app for my girlfriend for our anniversary. The last thing that I need to do is to set local notifications that send out DAILY at 8 AM for an entire WEEK BUT with a different text each day  and have it repeat the following week with the same texts. For example: On every Monday at 8 AM I would like the notification to say "Good morning!". On every Tuesday at 8 AM I would like the notification to say "I hope you have a great day!" On every Wednesday at 8 am I would like the notification to say "Make sure to take care of yourself today!" So on and so forth. If anyone can help create this line of code for me then I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you so much and happy holidays!

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                         content.sound = .default
                         content.title = "Good Morning princess :)"
                         content.body = "You're the reason why my world spins...never forget that <3"
                        
                        
                        
                         
                         
                         var dateComponent = DateComponents()
                          dateComponent.hour = 8  // 8 AM
                         dateComponent.minute = 00
                         
                         
                          let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: true)
                         
                         let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
                         
                         
                        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                         
                         
                         
                         center.add(request) { (error) in
```

Comment: better to use UNNotificationServiceExtension to do the content part.

Comment: - Horst so switch out the UNMutableNotificationContent with UNNotificationServiceExtension? Do I not change anything else?

Comment: sorry, I gave you the wrong name. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications . The concept is trigger the notification in app and generate the content in UNNotificationContentExtension